# Layouts overlapping in android studios

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I am trying to make an application but When I try to use multiple layouts. But they are overlapping on one another.

[image]

[image]

These are the Layout files for the design

this is nav_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:background="#429B50"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

this is nav_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

This is activity home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>
<include layout="@layout/nav_home"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know it looks messy with multiple layout files but that's because i was trying different ways to solve the problem. Would really appreciate the help

Comment: You have to reduce the scope of the first layout, if you wanna the button to appear over another one be it only parent of the other view, not the entirely layout

Answer (score 0):

In your activity home, which is a RelativeLayout, you include these:

```
<include layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>
<include layout="@layout/nav_home"/>
```

You must use the proper attributes for these layouts to be positioned correctly.  
If you want the button to be at the bottom of your activity, do this:

```
<include layout="@layout/nav_home"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

You may have to set other attributes too.
Also in `nav_home.xml` I think you should set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` at least for the height, maybe for width too and remove all these attributes that apply only inside a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Button at the bottom right corner then you can use one of these 2 ways:

1. You can use constraint layout and add these 2 constraints to Button
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

   ```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:text="Button"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
   ```
2. Modify Relative layout and add this

   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that will resolve your problem... :)